# Implement a Foursquare-like Check-In into a wordpress/buddypress install

Tags: php, wordpress, foursquare, buddypress, checkin

I am working on a pretty challenging project (at least challenging for me and my modest skills), which is based on Buddypress. Basically, I have this Buddypress Install, which I modified to fit my needs, which are for the most part localization services.

My groups component are now geo-localised, and everything looks fine. The thing is, I would like my users to be able to check-in the group when they are on location, as you would on Foursquare. I was wondering if anyone could help me with that. Is there a plugin available to do such a thing ? Or maybe a tutorial on how to make one ? Somebody might have already done this, or has an idea on how I could make it work in Buddypress.

I would appreciate any insight on this as I don't really know where to look first. I threw a glance at the foursquare API, but I would like to be able to use its functionalities without having to go through foursquare to check-in.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

There is BP Foursquare API ( http://wpmu.org/daily-tip-want-to-connect-buddypress-with-foursquare-check-out-the-new-bp-foursquare-api/) that connects your BuddyPress powered website to the XML or JSON Foursquare API. This is not plug & play solution.